# Compare a string array component with a character

Tags: c, arrays, string, token

I have this function: `int foo(char *string, int x, int y)` 
Example input is: `-.-..-...-.` The program tokenises the string with the delimiter `-`. Then it counts the `.` in the tokens. The problem is the `db` variable does not change.  After the counting the `db` has to be higher than `x` and lower than `y`. So -.-..-...- 2 3, the solution has to be 2.

```
    char *token;
    int length;
    int i;
    int db=0;
    int igaz=0;
    int j=1;

    token = strtok(string, "-");
    length = strlen(token);

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        length = strlen(token);

        for(i=0; i<length; i++);
        {
            if(token[i] == '.')
            //if(strcmp(token[i],'.')==0)
            {
                db++;
            }
        }

        if(db >= x && db <= y)
        {
            igaz++;
        }
        db=0;

        token = strtok(NULL, "-");
        j++;

    }
    return igaz;
```

Comment: What are  x and y?

Comment: @Bela Karalyos : I've edited the question for spelling and grammar, but this is still not a *minimal working example*, see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Additionally, please add some example inputs & expected outputs.

Comment: Also if you are sure that string just has '-' and '.', why do you use for loop. db = strlen(token); right?

Comment: Is the *whole thing* part of `foo()`? If so, please fix.

Comment: Explain why for -.-..-...- 1 1 solution is 3.

Comment: There is a `;` at the end of a `for` instruction: `for(i=0; i<length; i++);`! The following block is only executed when `i` is length...

Comment: @Toby, you made an error while editing. Input is  -.-..-...- 2 3 and not  -.-..-...- 1 1. I think Béla Karalyos updated it while you were editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code.
 1. For loop with semi colon.

```
for(i=0; i<length; i++);
```

This will just make the thread loop. But it will not execute the for loop body.

2. strlen() will return string length excluding '\0' at the end. So your for loop should be from 0 to length as below.

> `for(i=0; i<=length; i++);`

3. For loop is unnecessary as string has only '-' and '.'

This will do that.

```
int foo(char *string, int x, int y)
{
    char *token;
    int igaz =0;
    int db   = 0;

    token = strtok(string, "-");

    while(token != NULL)
    {
       db = strlen(token);


       if(db >= x && db <= y)
       {
           igaz++;
       }

       token = strtok(NULL, "-");

    }
    return igaz;

}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. With the next line: if(token[i] == '.'). What could be the problem?

Comment: @BélaKaralyos I updated the answer. Hope you find answer to your question.

Comment: God, i did not even notice that, it did not give me any error, or warning.. It is working now!